# jQuery opacity animation not working but any other animation does

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a really strange problem: I am using jQuery v11 on the latest Chrome on localhost. While I manage to use jQuery.animate() on my website with any elements and features (including opacity), I have one element that I just can't.

I tried to trigger the animation within and outside the $(document).ready() function and they both resulted in the same thing. I tried with fadeTo, fadeIn/fadeOut, animate opacity, all of them the same thing. The animation starts but after a certain percentage it just doesn't continue and jumps right to the end. *I also tried it with e.g. padding and it works perfectly.*

I am using the callback too but removing or adding it did not affect performance on either cases. Also, I have browsed through dozens or even more questions already, so I feel I did my research.

Thank you for your help!

JavaScript:

```
$("#nb_copy").stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300, function()
{
$(this).css("background-position", "-16px").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='notes_buttons'>
<a id='nb_copy' data-info=''>C</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#notes_buttons
{
    width: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    right: -24px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

div#notes_buttons a
{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;

    background: red url("/db/sprite.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Note: I would like to use this animation in the following situation: I am animating the opacity (see, here it works...) of the parent div, then when the nb_copy button is pressed, it fades out, changes the bg position and fades back.

If I use really long animations (3000) and add a delay, the first animation interrupts after about 40%, then after the 3000 ms are over, it counts the delay and then the new animation. This way I have no problem with the animation. Also, if I do not use the callback, it is working. But the two interrupt each other somehow...

if I only use the .css in the callback, it applies instantly (the background position) but the animation runs smoothly.

I already spent about 1.5 hours on such a small thing... Well, if I reproduce the code above in JSfiddle, it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/g6z4xx16/. I am also using Zeroclipboard with the same button, may it be the problem?

In case I get it out of the Zeroclipboard nest, and put it into a simple click trigger, the same result.

Comment: You can use fadeToggle() instead.

Comment: No difference sadly, Arjun :( Exactly the same story.

Comment: Added something new. Take a look it. Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: Well, in the end I succeeded with a setTimeOut(). I tried plenty of combinations afterwards again (removing CSS, HTML and JS elements), but did not work with toggles, fades and animations. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why to make simple work complicated, just use `fadeToggle()` instead.

Simply change your code to this :

```
$("#nb_copy").fadeToggle(function()
{
$(this).css("background-position", "-16px").fadeToggle();
});
```

Using `fadeToggle()` is better because `animate()` is used to make custom animations.

> In your code place your `<style>` tag before the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue why but while it does work in JSFiddle, it does not work in my code. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: And by the way, this was a great lesson to simplify my work next time :)

Comment: I have this in the head:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/db/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/db/library.js"></script>` and the rest at the end of the body (printed out, not in a separate file) o_o